# Delete Multiple rows with same column name

Tags: mysql, sql

My Database table structure below: I want to DELETE all rows under the FIELD 2 column, because they have same values that would be used once in my database design.
        Please i need help on this...

```
   ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    +---+----------+----------+---------+---------+
    +ID + FIELD 1  + FIELD 2  + FIELD 3 + FIELD 4 +
    +---+----------+----------+---------+---------+
    + 1 +  AAA     +  1234    +  ABC    +   Y     +
    + 2 +  AAA     +  1234    +  DEF    +         +
    + 3 +  AAA     +  1234    +  GHI    +         +
    + 4 +  BBB     +  1234    +  ABC    +         +
    + 5 +  CCC     +  1234    +  JKL    +         +
    +---+----------+----------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Deleting all rows under a column would be deleting all rows in the table since every row us under every column. Are you trying to just remove the column since it appears to always be the same? Or are you just trying to remove records where that column is a duplicate value?

Comment: If the column is nullable, then `UPDATE my_database_table SET \`FIELD 2\` = NULL;`

Comment: Do you want to remove the column `Field2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Believe this should do the trick..

```
UPDATE table_name SET FIELD2 = NULL
```

This will set all of the values in that column to NULL (empty)

Comment: Thanks Alex, And to community members i just needed to make field2 empty

Comment: Np, glad I was of help :)

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you mean, but I came up with two answers to two questions you are possibly asking:

1. If you want to delete all rows that have a value in field2, then:

   ```
   DELETE FROM 'table' WHERE field2<>''
   ```
2. If you want to clear the value of field2 from all rows then:

   ```
   UPDATE 'table' SET field2=''
   ```

Answer (score 0):

use UPDATE to make null the value

```
 UPDATE TABLE SET `FIELD 2` = '';
```

or

```
 UPDATE TABLE SET `FIELD 2` = NULL;
```